# Remove package from Angular 11

Tags: angular

How to remove package from Angular 11 ?

My `package.json` file is like below.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.2.9",
    "@angular/common": "~11.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.9",
    "@angular/core": "~11.2.9",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.9",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.9",
    "bootstrap": "^3.4.1",
    "jquery": "^2.1.0",
    "ngx-useful-swiper": "^10.0.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "swiper": "^6.6.2",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.3"
  },
```

I would like to remove `ngx-useful-swiper` package. I used `npm uninstall --save  ngx-useful-swiper`. I am getting this error `No matching version found for @types/jquery@^2.1.0.`

[image]

Comment: I assume your dev dependencies in package.json is having @types/jquery.... remove that line and run npm uninstall again

Comment: Thanks @AlaksandarJesusGene your solution is working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
npm unistall packagename
npm clean cache --force
```